# Duplicate emails - Spring Integration Mail

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-integration, imap

I am trying to setup a integeration flow to read UNSEEN emails from a mailbox and do some process on those. I have done the initial setup as below and I am having two issues.

```
   @Bean
   public IntegrationFlow mailListener() {
      return IntegrationFlows.from(Mail.imapInboundAdapter(CONNECTION_URL)
                              .shouldDeleteMessages(false)
                              .shouldMarkMessagesAsRead(true)
                              .searchTermStrategy(this::searchTerm)
                              .simpleContent(true)
                              .autoCloseFolder(false),
                      e -> e.poller(Pollers.fixedRate(5000).maxMessagesPerPoll(100).taskExecutor(taskExecutor())))
              .<Message>handle((payload, header) -> logMail(payload))
              .get();
   }

   @Bean
   private TaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
      ThreadPoolTaskExecutor threadPoolTaskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
      threadPoolTaskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(10);
      threadPoolTaskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(20);
      threadPoolTaskExecutor.setQueueCapacity(200);
      threadPoolTaskExecutor.setRejectedExecutionHandler(new ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy());
      threadPoolTaskExecutor.setKeepAliveSeconds(500);
      threadPoolTaskExecutor.setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown(true);
      threadPoolTaskExecutor.initialize();
      return threadPoolTaskExecutor;
   }

   private SearchTerm searchTerm(Flags flags, Folder folder) {
      SearchTerm[] searchTerms = {new FlagTerm(new Flags(Flags.Flag.SEEN), false)};
      return new AndTerm(searchTerms);
   }
```

**Issue 1**
I am seeing a lot duplicate messages. The same emails are read again.
I have also added a SearchTerm to filter the messages. Am I doing something wrong here?

**Issue 2**

When there are a lot of emails in mailbox (approx: 600000). ImapInboundAdapter tries to fetch all of them at once even when I
have set max-messages-per-poll on the Poller. If I set max-fetch-size on the adapter then, It only fetches the configured number of
messages but then processing is really slow around 5-10 sec/email. Fetch process ( Search -> flagging all the emails --> fetching the
content ) takes a lot of time . So my second question here is , How can I increase the performance to process around 200000 emails on daily basis?

Any Suggestions would be helpful. Thanks

Comment: Perhaps your server doesn't support the SEEN flag? See the `DefaultSearchTermStrategy` in `ImapMailReceiver` fir the logic it uses to figure out if a message has been seen.

Comment: I have verified the server supports the SEEN flag.

Comment: Do you close the folder somewhere after fetching content? How often do you do that?

Comment: I don't close the folder after fetching. I was getting FolderClosedException so I set the autoCloseFolder to false as well as simpleContent flag to true.

Comment: Any suggestions ??? Thanks in Advance